# to send a email using c# using compact framework

Tags: windows-ce

i have a pocket pc with windows cE6.0. I wanted to send a email using compact framework in c#.
i have tried the following code code. but i always get error at the line `smtp.Send(message)` stating `smpt exception unhand led`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
   msg.From = new MailAddress("murugandeepika7@gmail.com");
   msg.To.Add("deepikamurugan43@gmail.com");
   msg.Subject = "email7";
   msg.Body = "sample body";
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
   smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

Comment: can you please paste the complete exception?

Comment: Try adding the port like this:  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to connect and send with Gmail:

```
        // Connect to email                
        var mailclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
```

Comment: What reference needs to be added? For me (Windows CE 6), this code alone won't compile because SmtpClient is not recognized/immediately resolvable.

Comment: Normally System.Net.Mail but I think Windows CE has its own set of issues, like these posts indicate:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44b86f94-da59-4a0c-8a68-7493af8bb2f3/about-sending-mail-from-ce-50-vbnet?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

Comment: The OP used only one tag: windows-ce